# Linq Grouping Question

Tags: linq

I'm trying to group by categories;

let's say that I have two tables named as follows:

`Products`, `ProductTypes`

```
var foo = (from products in context.PRODUCTS
   join producttype in context.PRODUCTTYPE
   group producttype by new {producttype.name, producttype.producttypeid, products.productid} into g
   select new 
   {
       ProductName = g.Key.name, 
       ProductID = g.Key.producttypeid, 
       NumItems = g.Distinct().Count()
   });
```

Here's sample data

```
Product (productId, Name, ProductTypeID)
-------
1 ProductA 1
2 ProductB 1
3 ProductC 2
4 ProductD 3

ProductType (ProductTypeID, Name)
-----------
1 CategoryA
2 CategoryB
3 CategoryC

ProductSubType (ProductSubtypeID, Name, ProductID)
--------------
1 ProductSubType1 1
2 ProductSubType2 1
3 ProductSubType3 2
4 ProductSubType4 2
5 ProductSubType5 2
6 ProductSubType6 2
7 ProductSubType7 3
```

my results are as follows

```
CategoryA 1
CategoryA 1
CategoryB 1
CategoryC 1
```

I'm expecting the results to be

```
CategoryA 2
CategoryB 1
CategoryC 1
```

This is correct, except `CategoryA` should show up as `CategoryA 2`.

I'm not sure what simple syntax I'm missing here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why do you join by products.productid? Are there more than one productID in Products table?

Comment: I join by the productid to get to other tables I need to filter the initial result (active status, price, etc).  There isn't more than 1 productID in the Products table.

Comment: So you should remove it from the group statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently grouping by a composite key (name, producttypeid, productid) - any unique combination of these will show up as a separate group. It sounds like you want to group by just `producttypeid`.

**Edit:**

First of all your LINQ query seems to be missing a part (the join criteria), it should be more like this to even compile:

```
var results = (from products in Products
                join  productType in ProductTypes 
                on products.ProductTypeID equals productType.ProductTypeId
                group productType by new { productType.Name, productType.ProductTypeId, products.ProductId } into g
                select new
                {
                    ProductName = g.Key.Name,
                    ProductID = g.Key.ProductTypeId,
                    NumItems = g.Distinct().Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Your composite key (Name, ProductTypeId, ProductId) defines the unique elements by which your data will be grouped by. Looking at the sample data you provided you can quickly see that there are four unique combinations:

```
(Name, ProductTypeId, ProductId) 
(CategoryA, 1, 1)
(CategoryA, 2, 1)
(CategoryB, 3, 2)
(CategoryC, 4, 3)
```

That's why you have the output you provided:

```
 (Name, ProductId) 
    CategoryA 1
    CategoryA 1
    CategoryB 1
    CategoryC 1
```

To get the groups you do want to have, a regular Linq group join would do (names normalized to camel case):

```
var ProductTypeList = (from productType in ProductTypes
                        join product in Products
                        on productType.ProductTypeId equals product.ProductTypeID into prod
                        select new
                        {
                            ProductTypeId = productType.ProductTypeId,
                            Name = productType.Name,
                            Products = prod.ToList(),
                            NumItems = prod.Count()

                        }).ToList();

foreach (var item in ProductTypeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Name, item.NumItems);
}
```

Output:

```
CategoryA : 2
CategoryB : 1
CategoryC : 1
```

Let me know if this is what you were after.

Comment: @BrokenGlass All three of those should all be unique.  If I group by just producttypeid, how do I pull the values of the others?

Comment: @dave2118: The problem seems to be that in the product type `CategoryA` there are two products, each with a different product id, hence each shows up in a different group. You want them in the same group, do you not?

Comment: @BrokenGlass correct, the productID's are different, however it's the prodcuttypeid I need for filtering.

Comment: why don't you remove the `productID` from the grouping then?

Comment: Then it displays CategoryA 1, not CategoryA 2

Comment: It would help if you would add some sample data to your question and the output you expect given that sample data

Comment: Thanks, I posted it in the original post.